# How to make function run after react loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, frontend, jsx

I have this function , inside my react project , witch will create and load a table. After the function there is my html code , but everytime i execute my code the `document.getElementById` gots undefined .I try to use `onLoad` inside the `div` , but the function don't execute.

I try to run the function after return but its still not working.I already changed the code so much that I don't know what to do anymore.Can somebody help.Thanks

```
export default function Calendario(){
 function desing_calendario(){
    let height = 5
    let width = 7
    var html = "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>";
  
    for (let i = 0;i < height;i++){
     html += "<tr>" 
     for(let a = 0;a < width;a++){
       html += "<td>"
       html += (a+1)
       html += "</td>"
     }
     html += i
     html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>"
  
    document.getElementById('calendario').innerHTML = html ;
  }
 return(
        <div id='calendario' onload="desing_calendario()">
        </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: I suggest you follow this tutorial, which will cover such basics. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0

Comment: Your desired HTML looks to be invalid. A `<td>` should not have text nodes as adjacent siblings - it should only have `<td>` siblings.

Comment: You generally shouldn't be making imperative manipulations to the DOM like this in a React project. I'm sure this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I think you just need to find some good tutorials that cover the basics of working with React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going too much into the specifics of "what" you are trying to accomplish with tables and what not. Let's just go straight to arrow functions. They will help your code be more concise and certainly help with any binding issues you may run into. Just a quick look I think you can change the first line of the desing_calendario function to be:

```
const desing_calendario = () => {
```

then with onload you can simply reference the variable for the function

```
onload={desing_calendario}
```

With that said, it would be worth your time to learn more about hooks. Specifically useEffect in this case. You're already using a functional component. So, the work wouldn't be too much to make the migration. Also, I would suggest using a while loop instead of the old for loop syntax you have there. Would be cleaner. while(i < height) {....some code; i++}. But that's just extra.